# Why does the following use of PLupload not work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, plupload

I am having trouble with hiding an element that is used as file select for PLupload.

The following code works in Chrome, Firefox, IE10,...
Click "clickme", then clicking "Me no work in IE" will open a CommonDialogBox to select files, and "Hello!" will appear.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hZY67/13
For IE8:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/hZY67/13/show

**Observation**: In IE8 the CommonDialogBox doesn't pop up, but "Hello!" appears

Now remove display:none from the css.=> **problem solved**

**Conclusion: When an element is attached to PLupload as fileselect, and a parent element's display is toggled, the connection between the fileselect and PLupload breaks.**

Any light on this situation and possible workaround appreciated :)

Comment: To run the jsFiddle in IE8, just go to http://fiddle.jshell.net/hZY67/11/show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=2381#p2381

> @E-SPAR, Plupload needs to measure elements to generate file dialog trigger and position it properly, which obviously is not possible on elements having: display:none;. You might want to call refresh, after you show up your dialog.
>
> In case of Plupload UI widget:
>
> `$('#uploader').plupload('getUploader').refresh();`